# Showing all groups and count items in given group (including 0 results)

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, left-join

I have two tables: `class` and `student`. I want to get all existing classes and get number (counted) of students per given class. Trick is I want to show also a class that has `0` student.

Table "**class**":

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "class";
CREATE TABLE class(
  class_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  class_name VARCHAR
);


INSERT INTO class (class_name) VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO class (class_name) VALUES ('B');
INSERT INTO class (class_name) VALUES ('C');
```

Table "**student**":

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "student";
CREATE TABLE student(
  student_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  student_name VARCHAR,
  class_id numeric
);

INSERT INTO student (student_name, class_id) VALUES ('Mike', 1);
INSERT INTO student (student_name, class_id) VALUES ('Jessica', 1);
INSERT INTO student (student_name, class_id) VALUES ('Thomas', 1);

INSERT INTO student (student_name, class_id) VALUES ('Jacob', 2);
INSERT INTO student (student_name, class_id) VALUES ('Izabella', 2);
```

My query works, but does `NOT` show the class `C`  with `0` students in:

```
SELECT class_name, student.class_id, COUNT(DISTINCT student_id) AS num_students
FROM student
LEFT JOIN class ON student.class_id = class.class_id
GROUP BY student.class_id, class.class_name;
```

Above query gives me the following result:

| class_name | class_id | num_students |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| B | 2 | 2 |

I would love to be able to get something like this instead:

| class_name | class_id | num_students |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| B | 2 | 2 |
| C | 3 | 0 |

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN class ON student.class_id = class.class_id`

Comment: If you do left join, you're going to retain left table's values. If your left table is student, that's the table which the join will be based on. If you want to enforce all class values, you need to have class as the left table inside the join (as per answer below), or leave it in the right side and use the right join (as per EAW suggestion).

Comment: Btw, doublecheck your ddl that generates the tables: you may not want to use double quotes on table names when you create them, and you also need to specify the amount of varchar you want to allocate for "*class.class_name*" and "*student.student_name*" columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description, it appears that your query is intended to answer the question "For each class, how many unique students are enrolled?" Unfortunately, the query you've written answers a slightly different question; i.e., "For each class with at least one enrolled student, how many unique students are enrolled?"

For readability/clarity, I suggest putting `class` first in the `FROM` clause since it is the driving table. For queries with more than one table, always qualify the column names so that it's easy to identify the source without having to reference each table's DDL. In the select list, only reference columns from outer joined tables when necessary since they will be `NULL` if the join criteria isn't met.

The following query produces the requested results:

```
SELECT class.class_name, class.class_id, COUNT(DISTINCT student.student_id) AS num_students
  FROM class
  LEFT JOIN student
    ON class.class_id = student.class_id
  GROUP BY class.class_id
  ORDER BY class.class_name;
```

Note that this query only groups by `class.class_id`. Since `class_id` is the primary key, including other columns from `class` in the list of grouping expressions is redundant since each is fully dependent on `class_id`.

There should be a foreign key constraint on `student(class_id)` referencing `class(class_id)`.

Comment: thank you for extensive, thorough reply. It works!